# How to write a while loop with multiple conditions in C

Tags: c, while-loop, conditional-statements, logical-operators, logical-and

I tried doing a *while* loop with multiple conditions, but I just can't figure out how to make it work. I've made a short example of what I kind of tried:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main () {
    int Num;

    printf("Please enter an odd integer between 5-20: ");
    scanf("%d", &Num);

    while ((Num % 2 == 0) && (5 > Num) && (20 < Num)) {

        printf("Not a valid input!");
        printf("Please enter an odd integer between 5-20: ");
        scanf("%d", &Num);
    }
}
```

I believe I'm using the correct logical operator, right?

Comment: There are no numbers both smaller than 5 and larger than 20.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope, you're wrong. Think of the logic

```
(5>Num) && (20<Num)
```

`Num` cannot be `<5` and `>20` at the same time. You either

- need the logical OR operator
- Change the range to something like `(Num > 5) && (Num < 20)` or something

Comment: Or meant `(5<Num) && (20>Num)`.

Comment: @SouravGhosh Oh god yeah, I have completely mixed them up damn hahah, thanks man! It works now